# Face-Font not working in Chrome Extension MV3

Tags: javascript, css, json, google-chrome-extension, font-face

I'm trying to add local fonts to my Chrome Extension but it doesn't work. I tried adding permission to the web_accessible_resources on the manifest.json, tried adding the font-face code to the top of my html file inside style tags but no success.
I was using the import method but Chrome Store didn't like it.

The content_script.js gets loaded when user access web.whatsapp page and my code gets appended to it's body.

**content_script.js**

```
(function (){
    appendMainHtml = function(callbackFunction){
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

                var div = document.createElement('div'),
                url = chrome.runtime.getURL('widget/').replace('img/IconStop.svg', '');
                div.setAttribute("id", "inserted-html-box");
                div.setAttribute("extension-url", url);

                div.innerHTML = this.responseText;
                var child = document.body.firstChild;                
                
                document.body.insertBefore(div, child);
                callbackFunction();
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", chrome.runtime.getURL("/widget/index.html"), true);
        xhttp.send();
    },
    addScript = function(filePath){
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.setAttribute("src", chrome.runtime.getURL(filePath));
        document.head.appendChild(script);
    },
    addOnCallBack = function(){
        addScript("widget/style.css");
    },
    appendMainHtml(addOnCallBack);
})();
```

**widget/style.css**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Poppins-Bold", sans-serif;;
    font-weight: 700;
    src: url("chrome-extension://{{id}}/widget/fonts/Poppins/Poppins-Bold.ttf") format('truetype');
    src: local('Poppins-Bold');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Poppins-SemiBold", sans-serif;;
    font-weight: 600;
    src: url("chrome-extension://{{id}}/widget/fonts/Poppins/Poppins-SemiBold.ttf") format('truetype');
    src: local('Poppins-SemiBold');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Poppins-Medium", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    src: url("chrome-extension://{{id}}/widget/fonts/Poppins/Poppins-Medium.ttf") format('truetype');
    src: local('Poppins-Medium');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Poppins-Regular", sans-serif;;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url("chrome-extension://{{id}}/widget/fonts/Poppins/Poppins-Regular.ttf") format('truetype');
    src: local('Poppins-Regular');
}
.panel-inputTitle {
    font-family: "Poppins-Medium", sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    line-height: 24px;
    opacity: 1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

**manifest.json**

```
"web_accessible_resources": [
        {
            "resources": [
                "widget/*.html",
                "*.js",
                "widget/img/*",
                "widget/fonts/*.ttf"
            ],
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
        }
    ],
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: No, I'm just seeing the text without style.

Comment: Encode the fonts as `data:`.